# Kivy. Python. It is possible to resize the main window such as the ratio between width and height remains constant during the process?

Tags: python, kivy, window, resize

I try to create a **video player** in kivy and I need that this player to maintain its main window's initial proportions between width and height when the user performs the resize event over it.

I tried this piece of code:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window


#These are the initial values and I need to maintain this ratio, w/h, constant all the way as long as the resize event is kicked on by my mouse.

w = 350
h = round(w/16*9) + 60
Window.size = (w,h)


def reSize(*args):
    # print(f'{args[1]} ;{args[2]}')
    w = args[1]
    h = w/16*9 + 60
    Window.size = (w,h)
    return True

Window.bind(on_resize = reSize)
Window.minimum_height = round(w/16*9) + 60
Window.minimum_width = w
```

and the result is hideous.
A huge window appears filling half of my screen and is completely inoperable.

I tried to find an event like `onSizeChanged`, like in matplot for example, but there isn't one in kivy framework.

Any suggestions or hints, please?

Comment: would you consider defining the graphics property resizable = 0 in config.ini?  this would disable the mouse drag resize but you would have to try giving the user a resize tool in the app; if Kivy even allows that.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the size of the video player in your `reSize()` method rather than adjusting the size of the main window?

Comment: John Anderson, I want video container to remain stuck on the window edges as it is in the initial set up, which partially is obtained even in this conditions, and in addition the main window to be resized such as all its edges to remain permanently in contact with video edges. Like classic players behave: you can't drag the corners in any way you want, but only to maintain the original proportions of the video which is played.